# how to solve apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: kali-linux

```
root@kali:~# apt-get dist-upgrade

 Reading package lists... Done

 Building dependency tree 
      
 Reading state information... Done

 Calculating upgrade... Error!

 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable

 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

 or been moved out of Incoming.

 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.2.0-14 is to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by 
held packages.
```

Comment: Try apt-get uodate first to get the packages before doing the upgrade.

Comment: @John you mean `sudo apt-get update`, but that probably wont resolve this issue

Comment: In Root may not need Sudo. But in my regular user name, I use sudo apt-get update. Depends on user name on my machine.

Comment: i already used sudo apt-get update and didn't solve anything

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/full-upgrade-to-debian-testing-fails-due-to-libc6-dev-breaks-libgcc-8-dev

Answer (score 1):

This is an apparent bug with the gcc-10 packages in Debian: they renamed a package and removed the transitional packages before the release of Bullseye. The following packages were renamed (to match stated convention/debian policy more closely, I think):

- libgcc1 -> libgcc-s1
- lib64gcc1 -> lib64gcc-s1 (on 32 bit architectures only)
- lib32gcc1 -> lib32gcc-s1 (on 64 bit architectures only)
- libx32gcc1 -> libx32gcc-s1 (on x86_64 only)
- a few others on less common arches

The newly-renamed packages have a `Provides: libgcc1` (etc.) property, but it
appears that apt is preferring a real (old) libgcc1 package over a virtual
package that is only "provide"d by the newer package, since it's trying to not
break your system. I am not familiar with the details of the internals of
dependency resolution and installation order, but that's how I understand the
problem anyway.

The way to really solve the problem, at least until a fix in the distro, is to provide "real" (but empty "transitional") packages named using the old name, that depend on the package's new name. I have done this over at https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat (including a repo to add with the packages). There's more details about the problem, and instructions to use my workaround, over there.

Since I know link-only answers are frowned upon, here's approximately what my workaround effectively does:

You can use the `equivs` package to make your own empty packages. (You may need to do this on a different system or undo your repo changes, to be able to install equivs!) Once `equivs` is installed, you'll want to do something like this for each of the package renames:

```
# create equivs control file named libgcc1
equivs-control libgcc1.control

# edit equivs control file: you will need to set:
# - "Package" name to the old name
# - "Version" to something larger than the old version: 10.1.0-1 works
# - "Depends" to the new name
nano libgcc1.control

# Build a package - add `--arch i386` to make a 32-bit build
equivs-build libgcc1.control
```

You will then need to put this into an apt repo: **do not** just install it directly because these will replace the essential, real libgcc, which will keep you from running apt! Making a repo is beyond the scope here, check another question or just use the repo I already made.

Once these new "transitional" libgcc1 etc. are available in an apt repo and you update your sources to choose bullseye, apt will be able to dist-upgrade/full-upgrade correctly, and you can remove the transitional packages after the upgrade is done.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with your repository.
Login as a root user and update your repository.
Open terminal and run

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Replace the old repository with the new repository, save and run

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install -f
apt autoremove
apt clean
```