# Buster to Bullseye Upgrade Error

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-bullseye

I am trying to update my Raspberry Pi from Buster to Bullseye. I receive the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) 
but 8.3.0-6+rpi1 is to be installed
```

I found a workaround at [how to solve apt-get dist-upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1577742/how-to-solve-apt-get-dist-upgrade/1607419#1607419?newreg=6d65bb5d9ef7410cb0f630e881b8921e)

But the author's ***rpavlik*** directory no longer exists on the server.

Is there a solution available elsewhere? This was the only direct solution to the problem I was able to find. I'm a Linux novice, so I don't know how to do things like build repositories, so I'd need a script or step-by-step instructions. I hope those exist somewhere!

Comment: https://davyj0nes.github.io/post/private-repo-debian/ has some friendly instructions for how to host a repo of your own.

Comment: As it happens, https://github.com/tripleee/texlive-no-doc-equivs contains a very small demo of how to build packages with `equivs`. These days Github also lets you create a public repo for the build output IIRC; at the time, I uploaded the packages somewhere else (viz. https://packagecloud.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command prior to dist-upgrade:

sudo apt install gcc-8-base

Comment: Explaining how and why this fixes the problem will make this an answer.